# Coordinate transformation to obtain a metric that shows obviously is maximally symmetric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The following metric is given:

$$ ds^{2} = -dt^{2} + dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2} - 4\cosh^{2}(x/2)dtdx - 4\cosh^{2}(x/2)dx^2 $$ $$+ 4cosh(x/2)\sinh(x/2)dydx .$$

It is said that there exists a coordinate transformation for which the metric will be simplified to recognize that it is maximally symmetric. I tried the coordinate transformations used to obtain de Sitter and Anti-de Sitter conformal diagram, but I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

Does any one know which coordinate transformation can simplify my metric?

Comment: It is said where?

Comment: It's a homework question, there is no direct link to a book, but we use in general "GRAVITATION. AND COSMOLOGY: PRINCIPLES AND APPLICATIONS. OF THE GENERAL THEORY. OF RELATIVITY. STEVEN WEINBERG"

Comment: This is the original form of the metric in the homework: $$ ds^{2} = -dt^{2} + dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2} - 4\cosh(x/2)[\cosh(x/2)(dt+dx) - \sinh(x/2)dy]dx .$$